# What are the ramifications of upgrading from GCM in Android Play Services 6.x to 7.5.x

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I'm currently using *Google Play Services* v6.5.87 within an established Android application and *GCM* & push notifications are working well.

But as part of upgrading to current versions, I have seen that *GCM* uses a different process - eg [creating the new `json` configuration file etc](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client).

So, before I go and upgrade by creating this new `json` configuration file etc, I'm wondering what will happen to the existing versions of the app on the current (or older) builds if I do this? Will they cease to work? Do I need two separate *GCM* streams??

Comment: AFAIK, it is not necessary to create a `json` file for configuration. And previous `register` method is deprecated, its best you use newer `InstanceId` to get registered on GCM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new APIs should be essentially a drop in replacement for the current ones.

- Use InstanceID.getToken() instead of GoogleCloudMessaging.register()
- Add the GcmReceiver to your manifest instead of writing your own BroadcastReceiver
- Extend the GcmListenerService class and override the corresponding methods instead of extending IntentService.

You should be able to skip the early steps in the guide and only follow the ones [from here on](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest).

The json configuration file is not required. It is meant to streamline the integration of Google services, and includes the sender ID so new apps don't have to manually add it in.

Comment: For those following, some of the steps in the docs are missing (answered in other SO pages).

Comment: Also, using the full guide incl json won't damage your setup (I've tried it). Registration definitely works, still working on the receiving